# Ширина кнопки автоматически задавало высоту

Tags: android, xml, android-button

Есть `LinerLayout` в котором находятся 2 кнопки, и у них  есть `layout_weight="1"` соответственно они равномерно между собой делят ширину в `LinerLayout`. Как сделать чтобы высота соответствовала ширине которой задал наш `layout_weight="1"`. Нужно чтобы кнопка была квадратной не зависимо от ширины.

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minWidth="130dp"
                    android:minHeight="130dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:minWidth="130dp"
                    android:minHeight="130dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не сделаете этого в вашей XML разметке.
Тут есть пару способов:

- Простой и более костыльный где-нибудь в `onCreate()` взять ширину ваших кнопок и руками задать высоту равную ширине.
- Более правильный написать свою реализацию кнопки. Для этого создаете класс, который наследуется от View (хотя если вам только размер нужно изменить, то наследуйтесь от Button). В нем переопределить метод `onMeasure()`. В этом методе происходит измерение кнопкой своих размеров. Вот тут вы и берете ширину этой кнопки и делаете такой же высоту.